# convert a String of a certain size like 9 into string blocks of another size like 4

Tags: java, encryption, permutation

This is my code I'm trying to create a permutation cipher. The problem that I get into is when the plainText length % key length != 0 I get an error because the ending of the sub string it past the plainText length so it excedes length. my test passes plainText="abcdefg" key="0213" creating a permutation of "acbdegfh" but if the key is for example "021" I have an error because the block don't match up they turn into "abc" "def" "g" but the error occurs at "g" since it reaches the end plainText limit. Any suggestions on how to fix this....

```
   private String key;
   private String plainText;
   private String encryptedText=""; 

   public void encrypt() {
        for (int i=0, k=key.length(); i<plainText.length(); i=i+key.length()){
            String temp=plainText.substring(i,k);
            arrangeLetters(temp);
            k=k+key.length();
        }
    }

    private void arrangeLetters(String temp) {
        for (int i=0; i<temp.length(); i++){

            char movement=key.charAt(i);
            int position=Character.getNumericValue(movement);
            encryptedText+=temp.charAt(position);   
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is how is it defined in such a case and how you want to proceed. You have two options:

1. Pad the plaintext so that is a multiple of the key length. Special care should be taken into how you want to pad. Using PKCS#7 is not an option for such a classic cipher. You can use one special character which certainly isn't used in the plaintext so that you can filter it out later when decrypting. First sensible google result shows a python example [here](http://everything2.com/title/Permutation+cipher).

   If you can't know a special character, then use proper padding. For example, you could pad to the next multiple of the key with some random characters, encrypt the padded plaintext and when returning the ciphertext simply add the number of characters that were added. When you decrypt, you simply remove the last number characters that denote the number of padded characters. Decrypt the ciphertext using the permutation cipher and remove the padded characters because you now know how many there are.
2. Simply don't process the last block. This may be a problem with long keys, because the end of the plaintext will be plainly visible.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on the encrypt method:

First, perhaps change `String temp=plainText.substring(i,k)` to `String temp=plainText.substring(i,MIN(k,plainText.length())`, since there is no constraint that k is less than the plainText, yet you are creating a substring up to the kth character.

Second, I don't think you need a variable k, since k is always i + key.length() unless you hit the end of the word.  If you replace k with i + key.length() i think it still works...